# Changing Assets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Hi I love the Parse Anypic tutorial and it helped me a lot is there a way to change the assets like the "Home" Screen.

I tried changing the Default, Default@2x, Default-568h@2x, Default-667h@2x, Default-736h@3x. I changed those and ran the project and it was still the black Parse screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change them in Resources > Assets

Answer (score 1):

The anypic Xcode project using asset catalogs for storing the images for the launch screen and app icons. These are found in the images.xcassets under the anypic folder.

To change the launch images simply drag the correct image size into the launch image asset.

[image: This is where you can find the image asset.]

Comment: Thank you. I was probably confusing in my question but the assets I want to change are the ones right under the Assets folder https://www.dropbox.com/s/492vx5kbzyqrh0g/Screenshot%202015-04-21%2007.46.09.png?dl=0 those 4 pictures